# Display tooltip in line using CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm developing a sticky side bar menu with tool a tool tip feature. In Chrome and Safari, it renders correctly, however, the tooltip appears off centre in IE.

Here's the code that seems to be causing the problem:

```
/* Vertically center tooltip content for left/right tooltips */
.tooltip-left:after, {
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The above renders fine in Chrome and Safari, however not in IE. Only when I declare it like so does it work in IE

```
/* Vertically center tooltip content for left/right tooltips */
.tooltip-left:after, {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: -16px; /* different */
}
```

Can anyone offer any advice as to how to code this correctly, perhaps using `display: inline-block`?

Here's the full Fiidle: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/jxg4th86/3/

Answer (score 1):

Setting `bottom:0` instead of `bottom:50%` (or replacing with `top:0`) fixed the issue in all browsers for me. Give that a try and see if the result is what you want?

Comment: That did it! Cheers!

Comment: No worries. I take payment in beer :p

Comment: If you're ever in Belfast I'll buy you a Guinness!